# Javascript/JQuery remove from tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabindex

On an HTML form I have INPUT text box followed by a link, then followed by another INPUT text box. I want to remove the link from the tabindex / tab order:

```
<p>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="" />
<a href="..a url.." id="link1">more info</a>
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" value="" />
</p>
```

The tab order is field1, link1, field2 and I want it to be field1, field2 without link1 in the tabindex / order at all. Aside from reordering via the `tabindex` attribute, is there any way to remove link1 from tabbing altogether?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can achieve this with html:

```
<p>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="" />
<a href="#" id="link1" tabindex="-1">more info</a>
</p>

<p>
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" value="" />
</p>
```

You could also use jquery to do this:

```
$('#link1').prop('tabIndex', -1);
```

Comment: It works and it resolves a problem I have, but will it validate/is it crossbrowser compatible.? W3 says tabindex should be between 0 and 32767..?

Comment: It validates using transitional doctype (I didn't check any others) and worked in FF, safari, chrome, opera, and IE 6,7,8.