# How to remove the default tabindex in an APEX form?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In APEX 4.0, in a form that is using Template 7: Standard,  I set the tabindex on all of my fields to the order I wanted to tab through them. I would like for the cursor to start from tabindex="1" after the last one has been tabbed. However, APEX set all of the labels in my form to a default tabindex of 999. This results in tabbing through all the labels before coming back to my fields.

Why does APEX include the labels in the tab order? How do I remove this default tabindex?

Comment: Apex version? What theme do you use? What is the label template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am still not sure why APEX has a default value for tabindex, I did find out how to remove the tabindex from the labels.

This is modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987947/3508438):

Enter this piece of code into "Execute when Page Loads":

> $('label').each(function(){
>   this.tabIndex = -1;
>   
> });

#### Option #2

Another way of doing this is by [going directly to the label template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV1bJ.jpg) and removing the tabindex set there.

The only down side to this option is that you would have to edit all the different label templates (Required, Required with help, etc.) in order to remove their default tabindex.

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends on theme you're using, but a better solution than jQuery would be to apply CSS, perhaps something like

```
label { tabindex = -1; }
```

Comment: Here is a perf comparison, I think is apples to apples http://jsperf.com/css-vs-jquery-label, based on this one http://jsperf.com/css-vs-jquery-css a discussion found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675952/performance-pure-css-vs-jquery